# Expose corporate webservices to azure web role

Tags: azure

We have a corporate web services with back end SAP, CRM etc. We would like to expose this web service (java web service) so that azure web role can connect to corporate intranet web services.

Could someone please suggest which of below technologies will fit and why:
1. Windows Service Bus
2. Windows Azure Connect

Comment: Or you could use the VPN.

Answer (score 1):

or 3. VPN (Virtual Network).

Service bus will require some effort to get working, but is a good solution if your corporate network overlords are very picky about exposing endpoints. Windows Azure Connect creates a VPN-like tunnel, but requires that specific software be installed, configured and maintained. I have an app that successfully uses virtual networking and utilises existing VPN gateways and skills - very understandable to the security and networking people.

Comment: Does VPN a normal legacy VPN is something new to Windows Azure?

Comment: "Virtual Networking" is part of the June 2012 release of Azure. Virtual Networks can be used on their own, but also connected to a gateway, to do traditional site-to-site VPN connections.